# How to add a slot to my main window in Qt builder?

Tags: qt, builder, signals, slot

I am using Qt Builder to create a simple window.

I used the menu editor to add a menu.

Now, I figured out how to connect one of the menu items to the `close()` method of the main window. My problem is how to add a slot to the main window. Here is what I have:

```
private slots:
    void OnAbout();
```

However, I can't get this method to show up in the 'Signals and Slots Editor'. How can I get it to show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. You have to select the main window and hit F4 to add the function to the slots for the window.